# How to Move Large Number of Files to Original Directories?

Tags: command-line, command

I accidentally ran a command that moved the contents of all the subdirectories in my home folder to my home folder. Should I call it a loss and reinstall my system, or is there some command(s) I can use to move all of these files to their original directories? It would be too many files to move manually (over 150000).

This is the command I ran:

`find . - mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv "{}" . \; && find . -type d -empty -delete`

It's supposed to delete folders once the contents have been moved, but no folders were deleted.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what command did you run?

Comment: Many of these files are user settings. If you reinstall your system, it will probably not even touch your `/home/user8547` directory, and you won't regain your settings. Restoring from backup would be the best solution, but presumably you don't have that?

Comment: @Dylan I edited my question to include the command.

Comment: @Sparhawk. I have a cloud backup. My sync folder was in the home directory and all of its contents were moved to the home folder with the command I ran. I turned off sync with my cloud service within a couple minutes of running the command.

Comment: Ah right, but presumably this means you don't back up your dot files and settings.

Comment: @Sparhawk No, I don't.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling the entire system would be overkill, if you ran the command as non-root user. Even if you can't/won't restore all settings and files immediately, it would be far easier to create another user on the system and work as that user. You can still move over settings, data files, etc. from the old account as you find the need. (Keep in mind though that you'll need to `chown` the files to your new user when you move them. But there's a good chance that many of your 150000 files are things like your browser cache of thumbnails, which will regenerate anyway.)

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing this instead of just moving everything into a "temporary" folder, and rebuilding the pre-existing user from scratch? Creating a new user seems like a lot more work, and I'm not sure what the gain would be.

Comment: It occurs to me that I could get a copy of the default settings folder for Linux Mint (which is the Linux distro I use), which would save me the trouble of doing the impossible, which is remembering where every file goes. And then just re-customize all the settings manually. Would that be a solution, or is the problem deeper?

Comment: @user8547 Probably the default settings are fairly minimal. They probably don't even relate to the DE. You can create a new user and see, or just check out `/etc/skel` for what is created with new users.